# How to export YahooQuery Dict type modules to CSV from AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, yfinance

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_csv'` occurs with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'] 
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.asset_profile
df = (faang.asset_profile)
df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)
```

It happens with a lot of `Dict` type [YahooQuery modules](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/guide/ticker/modules/).  Changing `faang.asset_profile` to `faang.valuation_measures` (a `pandas:DataFrame` type) works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'] 
faang = Ticker(symbols)
faang.asset_profile
df = pd.DataFrame(faang.asset_profile).T
df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)
```